# Django-cms root not found on production using i18n

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv

Currently on django-cms 2.4.2. Encountered a peculiar problem, when on local machine where DEBUG=True, visiting 127.0.0.1/ will redirect to 127.0.0.1/en/. When running on a production server (virtualenvs, apache), visiting mysite.com/ will raise a 404 but display the home page behind while mysite.com/en/ displays the home page. Been trying to find the root of the problem but can't seem to figure out if it's in the urls, wsgi or settings.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ... apps ...
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

# Static files
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
else:
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
    handler500 = 'error_pages.views.server_error'
    handler404 = 'error_pages.views.custom_404'
    handler403 = 'error_pages.views.permission_denied'
    handler400 = 'error_pages.views.bad_request'
```

I have `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` and `cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware` added in settings.

In my Apache httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:27567

# Begin site configuration
<VirtualHost *:27567>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.$
    ErrorLog "/path/to/log/error_path.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Tried logging any errors that django might encounter and only received:

```
WARNING 2013-09-18 14:04:34,380 Not Found: /
```

**Edit:**

Seems like when Debug=True, the problem goes away. I have set allowed_hosts settings to `'localhost'` and `'domain.com'`. Have checked sequence of middleware loaded, i18n is set to true etc but still can't pinpoint where the issue lies.

**Edit 2:**

Just found the problem. It lies in the error pages where the views for error pages are:

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def server_error(request):
    return render(request, '500.html')
```

Most likely a clash between django-cms' urls.